# Loadrunner controller issue

Tags: loadrunner

I'm trying to do performance testing on a silverlight application.

Below are my transaction: Login, launch/login silverlight application(no credentials required), enter transaction, silverlight exit, application logout. (i first need to loginto web application to access silverlight and silverlight doesn't require userid or pwd)

I've recorded the script in Vugen and played it, it is working fine.

When i use controller for 30 users having 5 iteration each, it is observed 2-5 silverlight launch/login is getting failed (only Silverlight is have the issue).

Here are the error messages:

```
Continuing after Error -27794: Failed to connect to server "xx.xxx.xx.xxx:80": [10060] Connection timed out
Continuing after Error -27725: Step download timeout (999 seconds) has expired when downloading resource(s). Set the "Step Timeout caused by resources is a warning" Run-Time Setting to Yes/No to have this message as a warning/error, respectively   [issued at Action.c(522)]c
```

**My question**: Why is this happening only for one or two login? example: userid 10 has five iteration, 4 of them are passed 1 failed, similarly for userid 15 and so on....

And this error is not consistent with the specific user id? why is it?

**Note:** I have recorded script using silverlight protocol.

Comment: It is also observed that most of the failures are while the other users are exiting. Not sure if this could be the cause.

Comment: turn on think time and pacing

Comment: @JamesPulley I've tried, but still the same issues.

Comment: Record three times.  You likely have missed a correlation related to state or session.  When you submit the incorrect information to the server then you get your connection shut down.

Answer (score 0):

"Connection timed out" usually means it's a server capability or network level issue. You cay try take some pcap log to check it.